# Error as I try to centre align the content on the report - What could be the reason for this?

Tags: tables, paragraphs, alignment

I am trying to centre the paragraphs, sub-paragraphs and table on the second page of the report.

The way I am trying to do is:

```
\paragraph{\begin{center}Document Information\end{center}}
```

But as I try to compile it, I get the following errors:

[image]

I could not understand the reason for this. Here is also my complete latex code, where I try to centre the paragraph, sub-para and table.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
    \title{Test Report}
    \author{Suhail}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \usepackage[landscape, margin=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage[yyyymmdd,hhmmss]{datetime}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \lhead{AA, BB (CC, DD)}
    \rhead{For Restricted Circulation Only}
    \lfoot{MFF-TTG/RT}
    \rfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
    \cfoot{}

    \begin{document}
    \maketitle


    \paragraph{\begin{center}Document Information\end{center}}

    \subparagraph{\begin{center}Document information is given in the table below\end{center}}

    \subparagraph{
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c| c| c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{S.No} & \textbf{Item} & \textbf{Information} \\
    \hline
    1 & Document ID & VFC-RRT/ER \\
    \hline
    2 & Document Generated At & \today \\
    \hline
    3 & Document Generated By & Me \\
    \hline
    4 & AFG Protocol ID & CV/1 \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    }
    \end{document}
```

What is the correct way to centre align the content? I want to centre align (horizontally and vertically) all the content on page 2. How could I do this?

Comment: Do you want to  centre-align the whole contents, or only paragraph titles?

Comment: @Bernard Center align the whole content but also want to understand why is this failing.

Comment: You only tried to centre paragraph titles. Paragrapgh contents would be the text following the title.

Comment: @Bernard I also tried adding `\begin{center}` after the paragraph but it gives an error

Comment: You should take a look at package `titlesec`.